# What does errors like "!=<" mean in agda and how to fix

Tags: algorithm, agda, theorem-proving

I can't find info about that on  http://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.3/ ,neither on the book "verified programming in agda".What does that mean? And where can I get to know more like this error?

The full error is `.cter !=< cter of type Set`

The code is sort of missy so if required I would post it later,which is about implementing simulated annealing algorithm .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It literally means that `.cter` is not a subtype of `cter`. Since the support for subtyping in Agda is really limited, it most likely means that Agda expected `.cter` and `cter` to be equal, but they aren't. In particular, `cter` is a (visible) variable from your code, while `.cter` is a hidden argument that Agda introduced and happens to have the same name.

I hope this helps. It is hard to be more specific without seeing the code, so if you are still stuck please try to find a small example with the same problem and post it here.

Comment: What do you mean by subtype? As far as I know agda do not have subtyping in the sense of  object-oriented languages

Comment: @doofin It doesn't, I think the subtyping has to do with the Universe Heirarchy (Set 0, Set 1, etc.), for most cases you can just read it as equality.